# find forces on ramp?

Tags: physics

[image]

According to the book, the formula is: 
$$
F\cos\theta - mg\sin\theta = ma
$$

It also says to set $a = 0$.

I don't understand how to solve it.

Also, why is $a = 0$? And isn't the right formula $F = ma$?

Comment: $a$ is the acceleration of the box.  If the box is being pushed at a constant speed, then its acceleration $a$ is $0$.

Comment: Proper formula might be $F=ma$ but this is taking into account the angle, which is why it's a bit different. Also, with $a=0$ we can get rid of the $ma$ and just have $Fcos\theta -mgsin\theta= 0$. From here just solve for $F$ and plug in $\theta$, $m$, and $g$. I'm assuming $g= -9.8m/s$?

Comment: So,

Fcos27 - 2352sin27 = 0

fcos27 = 1678.8

f = 1678.9 / 0.89 ?

Comment: @user416503 $240*9.8*sin(27)=1067.8$ edit: for me to receive a notification you should @ me or else I won't know if you replied.